# Xerces reports error when giving attribute to top-level element

Tags: xsd, xerces

I have the following schema which works fine:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="bindings">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="bind">
                    <xs:complexType>

                        <xs:attribute name="trigger" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute> <!-- trigger -->

                        <xs:attribute name="command" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute> <!-- command -->

                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element> <!-- bind -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> <!-- bindings -->
 </xs:schema>
```

However, when I try to define an attribute for the top level `bindings` element, I get an error no matter where I place the attribute code.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT**: It looks like there's some problem with either my Java XML code or Xerces.  If I change the XSD to give the top-level element the optional "parent" attribute, Xerves gives me the error `"Problem: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>."`  However, if I give the attribute any name //other// than "parent", it reports `Attribute 'parent' is not allowed to appear in element 'bindings'.`, just as you'd expect.

My Java code regarding XSD and Xerces is:

```java
    bindingsDocumentBuilderFactory =
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilderFactory bdbf = bindingsDocumentBuilderFactory;

    bdbf.setValidating(true);

    // I get the input stream here as "is"

    bdbf.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
                      "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    bdbf.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", is);
```

**EDIT 2**:

The XML file which is being validated:

```xml
<bindings parent="game/movement">
    <bind trigger="i" command="INVENTORY"/>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (see attribute named code):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <xs:element name="bindings"> 
        <xs:complexType> 
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
                <xs:element name="bind"> 
                    <xs:complexType> 
                        <xs:attribute name="trigger" use="required"> 
                            <xs:simpleType> 
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/> 
                                </xs:restriction> 
                            </xs:simpleType> 
                        </xs:attribute> 
                        <!-- trigger --> 
                        <xs:attribute name="command" use="required"> 
                            <xs:simpleType> 
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/> 
                                </xs:restriction> 
                            </xs:simpleType> 
                        </xs:attribute> 
                        <!-- command --> 
                    </xs:complexType> 
                </xs:element> 
                <!-- bind --> 
            </xs:sequence> 
            <xs:attribute name="code"/>
        </xs:complexType> 
    </xs:element> 
    <!-- bindings --> 
</xs:schema>
```

[image: Attribute]

Comment: I tried putting it there, and Xerces gives me the error: "     [java]     Problem: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>."  Even if I change all the "xs:" to "xsd:" I get that error.

Comment: If you can read the same file, once with the attribute and once without, then you have a serious bug in the version of Xerces that you're using. The XSD I've posted is valid beyond doubt - at the time of printing ;)... The error is rather showing that the XSD is not loaded properly... Can you post the Java code you're using?

Comment: Yeah, if the attribute is named anything *other* that "parent", I just get a normal "Attribute 'parent' is not allowed to appear in element 'bindings'." error.  But if it's named "parent", I get the "failed to read schema document error".  I'll update my post with my XML code.

Comment: Can you post the XML as well? It is really hard to understand from your description what is the problem. Also, you didn't say if you tried the XSD I've posted with your code, and if you got any errors.

Comment: I cut-and-paste your XSD file into mine and got the results I reported.  I'll add the XML file in question.